# How to add admob banner ads after each 3 video items

Tags: admob, ads, banner

Want to display admob banner ads after each 3 video item

I have the code below which works except it always hides atleast one real item in the listview because the ad displays at that position.

Example of the problem: I have a list of n times, and the adView is displaying at position 3. on the listview
I played around with increasing the size of the adapter everytime I return an ad but it didn't work very well.

Any ideas?

```
class LocalFoldedVideosFragment : SwipeBackFragment(), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener,
        OnReloadVideosListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, OnBackPressedListener {

private lateinit var mInteractionCallback: InteractionCallback
private var mLifecycleCallback: FragmentPartLifecycleCallback? = null

private var mVideoOpCallback: VideoListItemOpCallback<Video>? = null

private lateinit var mRecyclerView: SlidingItemMenuRecyclerView
private val mAdapter = VideoListAdapter()
private val mVideoDir by lazy {
    arguments?.get(KEY_VIDEODIR) as? VideoDirectory
}
private var _mVideos: MutableList<Video>? = null
private inline val mVideos: MutableList<Video>
    get() {
        if (_mVideos == null) {
            _mVideos = mVideoDir?.videos ?: ArrayList(0)
        }
        return _mVideos!!
    }
private var mLoadDirectoryVideosTask: LoadDirectoryVideosTask? = null

private lateinit var mBackButton: ImageButton
private lateinit var mCancelButton: Button
private lateinit var mSelectAllButton: Button
private lateinit var mVideoOptionsFrame: ViewGroup
private lateinit var mDeleteButton: TextView
private lateinit var mRenameButton: TextView
private lateinit var mShareButton: TextView
private lateinit var mDetailsButton: TextView
private lateinit var scrolable_banner_ads : AdView
private var _TOP: String? = null
private inline val TOP: String
    get() {
        if (_TOP == null) {
            _TOP = getString(R.string.top)
        }
        return _TOP!!
    }
private var _CANCEL_TOP: String? = null
private inline val CANCEL_TOP: String
    get() {
        if (_CANCEL_TOP == null) {
            _CANCEL_TOP = getString(R.string.cancelTop)
        }
        return _CANCEL_TOP!!
    }
private var _SELECT_ALL: String? = null
private inline val SELECT_ALL: String
    get() {
        if (_SELECT_ALL == null) {
            _SELECT_ALL = getString(R.string.selectAll)
        }
        return _SELECT_ALL!!
    }
private var _SELECT_NONE: String? = null
private inline val SELECT_NONE: String
    get() {
        if (_SELECT_NONE == null) {
            _SELECT_NONE = getString(R.string.selectNone)
        }
        return _SELECT_NONE!!
    }

fun setVideoOpCallback(callback: VideoListItemOpCallback<Video>?) {
    mVideoOpCallback = callback
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    val parent = parentFragment

    mInteractionCallback = when {
        parent is InteractionCallback -> parent
        context is InteractionCallback -> context
        parent != null -> throw RuntimeException("Neither $parent nor $context " +
                "has implemented LocalFoldedVideosFragment.InteractionCallback")
        else -> throw RuntimeException(
                "$context must implement LocalFoldedVideosFragment.InteractionCallback")
    }

    if (parent is FragmentPartLifecycleCallback) {
        mLifecycleCallback = parent
    } else if (context is FragmentPartLifecycleCallback) {
        mLifecycleCallback = context
    }
    mLifecycleCallback?.onFragmentAttached(this)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mLifecycleCallback?.onFragmentViewCreated(this)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    mLifecycleCallback?.onFragmentViewDestroyed(this)

    val task = mLoadDirectoryVideosTask
    if (task != null) {
        mLoadDirectoryVideosTask = null
        task.cancel(false)
    }
    if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        for (video in mVideos) {
            video.isChecked = false
        }
        mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutEnabled = true
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    App.getInstanceUnsafe()?.refWatcher?.watch(this)
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    mLifecycleCallback?.onFragmentDetached(this)

    targetFragment?.onActivityResult(targetRequestCode, RESULT_CODE_LOCAL_FOLDED_VIDEOS_FRAGMENT,
            Intent().putExtra(KEY_DIRECTORY_PATH, mVideoDir?.path)
                    .putParcelableArrayListExtra(KEY_VIDEOS,
                            mVideos as? ArrayList<Video> ?: ArrayList(mVideos)))
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_local_folded_videos, container, false)
    initViews(view)
    return attachViewToSwipeBackLayout(view)
}

private fun initViews(contentView: View) {
    val actionbar = mInteractionCallback.getActionBar(this)

    val titleText = actionbar.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_title)
    titleText.text = mVideoDir?.name

    mRecyclerView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.simrv_foldedVideoList)
    mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(contentView.context)
    mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(contentView.context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    mBackButton = actionbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_back)
    mCancelButton = actionbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel)
    mSelectAllButton = actionbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_selectAll)
    mVideoOptionsFrame = contentView.findViewById(R.id.frame_videoOptions)
    mDeleteButton = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_videoListOptions)
    mRenameButton = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_rename)
    mShareButton = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share)
    mDetailsButton = contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_details)

    mBackButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    mSelectAllButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    mRenameButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    mShareButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(this)

    contentView.post {
        if (Utils.isLayoutRtl(contentView)) {
            swipeBackLayout.enabledEdges = SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_RIGHT
        }
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() =
        if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            hideMultiselectVideoControls()
            true
        } else false

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_CODE_PLAY_VIDEO -> if (resultCode == RESULT_CODE_PLAY_VIDEO) {
            val video = data?.getParcelableExtra<Video>(KEY_VIDEO) ?: return
            if (video.id == NO_ID) return

            for ((i, v) in mVideos.withIndex()) {
                if (v != video) continue
                if (v.progress != video.progress) {
                    v.progress = video.progress
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i, PAYLOAD_REFRESH_VIDEO_PROGRESS_DURATION)
                }
                break
            }
        }
        REQUEST_CODE_PLAY_VIDEOS -> if (resultCode == RESULT_CODE_PLAY_VIDEOS) {
            val parcelables = data?.getParcelableArrayExtra(KEY_VIDEOS) ?: return
            val videos = Array(parcelables.size) { parcelables[it] as Video }
            for (video in videos) {
                val index = mVideos.indexOf(video)
                val v = if (index != -1) mVideos[index] else null
                if (v != null && v.progress != video.progress) {
                    v.progress = video.progress
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index, PAYLOAD_REFRESH_VIDEO_PROGRESS_DURATION)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.btn_back -> swipeBackLayout.scrollToFinishActivityOrPopUpFragment()

        R.id.itemVisibleFrame -> {
            val position = v.tag as Int
            if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                val video = mVideos[position]
                video.isChecked = !video.isChecked
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position, PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX_WITH_ANIMATOR)
                onVideoCheckedChange()
            } else {
                if (mVideos.size == 1) {
                    playVideo(mVideos[0])
                } else {
                    playVideos(*mVideos.toTypedArray(), selection = position)
                }
            }
        }
        R.id.checkbox -> {
            val video = mVideos[v.tag as Int]
            video.isChecked = !video.isChecked
            onVideoCheckedChange()
        }
        R.id.btn_top -> {
            val index = v.tag as Int

            val video = mVideos[index]
            val topped = !video.isTopped
            video.isTopped = topped

            VideoListItemDao.getInstance(v.context).setVideoListItemTopped(video, topped)

            val newIndex = mVideos.reordered().indexOf(video)
            if (newIndex == index) {
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index, PAYLOAD_CHANGE_ITEM_LPS_AND_BG)
            } else {
                mVideos.add(newIndex, mVideos.removeAt(index))
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(newIndex)
                mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(min(index, newIndex),
                        abs(newIndex - index) + 1)
            }
        }
        R.id.btn_delete -> {
            val video = mVideos[v.tag as Int]
            mVideoOpCallback?.showDeleteItemDialog(video) {
                onVideoDeleted(video)
            }
        }

        R.id.btn_cancel -> hideMultiselectVideoControls()
        R.id.btn_selectAll -> {
            if (mSelectAllButton.text == SELECT_ALL) {
                for ((index, video) in mVideos.withIndex())
                    if (!video.isChecked) {
                        video.isChecked = true
                        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index, PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX_WITH_ANIMATOR)
                    }
            } else {
                for (video in mVideos) video.isChecked = false
                mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mAdapter.itemCount,
                        PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX_WITH_ANIMATOR)
            }
            onVideoCheckedChange()
        }
        R.id.btn_delete_videoListOptions -> {
            val videos = checkedVideos ?: return
            if (videos.size == 1) {
                mVideoOpCallback?.showDeleteItemsPopupWindow(videos[0]) {
                    hideMultiselectVideoControls()
                    onVideoDeleted(videos[0])
                }
            } else {
                mVideoOpCallback?.showDeleteItemsPopupWindow(*videos.toTypedArray()) {
                    hideMultiselectVideoControls()

                    var start = -1
                    var index = 0
                    val it = mVideos.iterator()
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        if (videos.contains(it.next())) {
                            if (start == -1) {
                                start = index
                            }
                            it.remove()
                            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
                            index--
                        }
                        index++
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(start, mAdapter.itemCount - start)
                }
            }
        }
        R.id.btn_rename -> {
            val video = checkedVideos?.get(0) ?: return

            hideMultiselectVideoControls()
            mVideoOpCallback?.showRenameItemDialog(video) {
                val index = mVideos.indexOf(video)
                val newIndex = mVideos.reordered().indexOf(video)
                if (newIndex == index) {
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index, PAYLOAD_REFRESH_ITEM_NAME)
                } else {
                    mVideos.add(newIndex, mVideos.removeAt(index))
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(newIndex)
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(min(index, newIndex),
                            abs(newIndex - index) + 1)
                }
            }
        }
        R.id.btn_share -> {
            val video = checkedVideos?.get(0) ?: return

            hideMultiselectVideoControls()
            shareVideo(video)
        }
        R.id.btn_details -> {
            val video = checkedVideos?.get(0) ?: return

            hideMultiselectVideoControls()
            mVideoOpCallback?.showItemDetailsDialog(video)
        }
    }
}

override fun onLongClick(v: View) = when (v.id) {
    R.id.itemVisibleFrame ->
        if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE
                || mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutRefreshing) {
            false
        } else {
            mBackButton.visibility = View.GONE
            mCancelButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mSelectAllButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mRecyclerView.isItemDraggable = false
            mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutEnabled = false

            mRecyclerView.post {
                val itemBottom = (v.parent as View).bottom
                val listHeight = mRecyclerView.height
                if (itemBottom > listHeight) {
                    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, itemBottom - listHeight)
                }
            }

            val selection = v.tag as Int
            mAdapter.run {
                notifyItemRangeChanged(0, selection,
                        PAYLOAD_CHANGE_CHECKBOX_VISIBILITY or PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(selection + 1, itemCount - selection - 1,
                        PAYLOAD_CHANGE_CHECKBOX_VISIBILITY or PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX)

                mVideos[selection].isChecked = true
                notifyItemChanged(selection,
                        PAYLOAD_CHANGE_CHECKBOX_VISIBILITY or PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX_WITH_ANIMATOR)
                onVideoCheckedChange()
            }

            true
        }
    else -> false
}

private fun onVideoCheckedChange() {
    var checkedVideosCount = 0
    for (video in mVideos) {
        if (video.isChecked) checkedVideosCount++
    }
    when (checkedVideosCount) {
        mVideos.size -> mSelectAllButton.text = SELECT_NONE
        else -> mSelectAllButton.text = SELECT_ALL
    }
    mDeleteButton.isEnabled = checkedVideosCount > 0
    val enabled = checkedVideosCount == 1
    mRenameButton.isEnabled = enabled
    mShareButton.isEnabled = enabled
    mDetailsButton.isEnabled = enabled
}

private inline val checkedVideos: List<Video>?
    get() {
        var videos: MutableList<Video>? = null
        for (video in mVideos) {
            if (video.isChecked) {
                if (videos == null) videos = mutableListOf()
                videos.add(video)
            }
        }
        return videos
    }

private fun hideMultiselectVideoControls() {
    mBackButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mCancelButton.visibility = View.GONE
    mSelectAllButton.visibility = View.GONE
    mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility = View.GONE
    mRecyclerView.isItemDraggable = true
    mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutEnabled = true

    for (video in mVideos) {
        video.isChecked = false
    }
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mAdapter.itemCount,
            PAYLOAD_CHANGE_CHECKBOX_VISIBILITY or PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX)
}

private fun onVideoDeleted(video: Video) {
    val index = mVideos.indexOf(video)
    if (index != -1) {
        mVideos.removeAt(index)
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index)
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(index, mAdapter.itemCount - index)
    }
}

override fun onReloadVideos(videos: List<Video>?) =
        if (videos == null || videos.isEmpty()) {
            onReloadDirectoryVideos(null)
        } else {
            onReloadDirectoryVideos(
                    videos.filter {
                        it.path.substring(0, it.path.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar))
                                .equals(mVideoDir?.path, ignoreCase = true)
                    }.reordered())
        }

private fun onReloadDirectoryVideos(videos: List<Video>?) {
    if (videos == null || videos.isEmpty()) {
        if (mVideos.isNotEmpty()) {
            mVideos.clear()
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                hideMultiselectVideoControls()
            }
        }
    } else
        if (videos.size == mVideos.size) {
            var changedIndices: MutableList<Int>? = null
            for (i in videos.indices) {
                if (!videos[i].allEqual(mVideos[i])) {
                    if (changedIndices == null) changedIndices = LinkedList()
                    changedIndices.add(i)
                }
            }
            if (changedIndices != null) {
                for (index in changedIndices) {
                    mVideos[index] = videos[index]
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index) // without payload
                }
                if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    hideMultiselectVideoControls()
                }
            }
        } else {
            mVideos.set(videos)
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                hideMultiselectVideoControls()
            }
        }
}

override fun onRefresh() {
    if (mVideoOpCallback?.isAsyncDeletingItems == true) { 
        mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutRefreshing = false
        return
    }

    if (mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        hideMultiselectVideoControls()
    }

    if (mLoadDirectoryVideosTask == null) {
        mLoadDirectoryVideosTask = LoadDirectoryVideosTask()
        mLoadDirectoryVideosTask!!.executeOnExecutor(ParallelThreadExecutor.getInstance())
    }
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private inner class LoadDirectoryVideosTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Video>?>() {
    override fun onPreExecute() {
        mRecyclerView.isItemDraggable = false
        mRecyclerView.releaseItemView(false)
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): List<Video>? {
        val dao = VideoListItemDao.getInstance(contextRequired)

        var videos: MutableList<Video>? = null

        val videoCursor = dao.queryAllVideosInDirectory(mVideoDir?.path) ?: return null
        while (!isCancelled && videoCursor.moveToNext()) {
            val video = dao.buildVideo(videoCursor) ?: continue
            if (videos == null)
                videos = LinkedList()
            videos.add(video)
        }
        videoCursor.close()

        return videos?.reordered()
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(videos: List<Video>?) {
        onReloadDirectoryVideos(videos)
        mRecyclerView.isItemDraggable = true
        mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutRefreshing = false
        mLoadDirectoryVideosTask = null
    }

    override fun onCancelled(result: List<Video>?) {
        if (mLoadDirectoryVideosTask == null) {
            mRecyclerView.isItemDraggable = true
            mInteractionCallback.isRefreshLayoutRefreshing = false
        }
    }
}

private inner class VideoListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = mVideos.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
            ViewHolder(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                            .inflate(R.layout.video_list_item_video, parent, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
            onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
        } else {
            val video = mVideos[position]

            val payload = payloads[0] as Int
            if (payload and PAYLOAD_CHANGE_ITEM_LPS_AND_BG != 0) {
                separateToppedItemsFromUntoppedOnes(holder, position)
            }
            if (payload and PAYLOAD_CHANGE_CHECKBOX_VISIBILITY != 0) {
                holder.checkBox.visibility = mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility
            }
            if (payload and PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX != 0) {
                holder.checkBox.isChecked = video.isChecked

            } else if (payload and PAYLOAD_REFRESH_CHECKBOX_WITH_ANIMATOR != 0) {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(video.isChecked, true)
            }
            if (payload and PAYLOAD_REFRESH_ITEM_NAME != 0) {
                holder.videoNameText.text = video.name
            }
            if (payload and PAYLOAD_REFRESH_VIDEO_PROGRESS_DURATION != 0) {
                holder.videoProgressAndDurationText.text =
                        VideoUtils2.concatVideoProgressAndDuration(video.progress, video.duration)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemVisibleFrame.tag = position
        holder.checkBox.tag = position
        holder.topButton.tag = position
        holder.deleteButton.tag = position

        separateToppedItemsFromUntoppedOnes(holder, position)

        val video = mVideos[position]
        holder.checkBox.run {
            visibility = mVideoOptionsFrame.visibility
            isChecked = video.isChecked
        }
        VideoUtils2.loadVideoThumbnailIntoImageView(holder.videoImage, video)
        holder.videoNameText.text = video.name
        holder.videoSizeText.text = FileUtils2.formatFileSize(video.size.toDouble())
        holder.videoProgressAndDurationText.text =
                VideoUtils2.concatVideoProgressAndDuration(video.progress, video.duration)
    }

    private fun separateToppedItemsFromUntoppedOnes(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val context = contextThemedFirst
        val lp = holder.topButton.layoutParams

        if (mVideos[position].isTopped) {
            ViewCompat.setBackground(holder.itemVisibleFrame,
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.selector_topped_recycler_item))

            lp.width = DensityUtils.dp2px(context, 120f)
            holder.topButton.layoutParams = lp
            holder.topButton.text = CANCEL_TOP
        } else {
            ViewCompat.setBackground(holder.itemVisibleFrame,
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.default_selector_recycler_item))

            lp.width = DensityUtils.dp2px(context, 90f)
            holder.topButton.layoutParams = lp
            holder.topButton.text = TOP
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val itemVisibleFrame: ViewGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemVisibleFrame)
        val checkBox: CircularCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)
        val videoImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_video)
        val videoNameText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_videoName)
        val videoSizeText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_videoSize)
        val videoProgressAndDurationText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_videoProgressAndDuration)
        val topButton: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_top)
        val deleteButton: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete)

        init {
            itemVisibleFrame.setOnClickListener(this@LocalFoldedVideosFragment)
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this@LocalFoldedVideosFragment)
            topButton.setOnClickListener(this@LocalFoldedVideosFragment)
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this@LocalFoldedVideosFragment)

            itemVisibleFrame.setOnLongClickListener(this@LocalFoldedVideosFragment)
        }
    }
}

interface InteractionCallback : ActionBarCallback, RefreshLayoutCallback
}
```